# What is the value of $m+7$ if $m=12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $m=12$ then would it be $12+7$? Or would it be $5$? Would you have to subtract $7$ from $12$ to get $5$? Or replace $m$ with $12$ and get $19$?

Comment: Just replace $m$ with $12$ and get $12 + 7 = 19$.

Comment: $m+7$ is obviously bigger than $m$ not smaller, so it is 19 not 5.

Comment: In any expression, the role of a variable is a placeholder so that you can plug value into it. In an expression like $m+7$, the $m$ is the place you can insert value. If someone declares $m = 12$, then $m + 7$ becomes an alternate way to write down $12 + 7$. It has a value equals to $19$.

Comment: You ask would 'it' be $12+7$ but the answer depends on what you mean by it. I know that sounds awkward but I don't mean it to be.

Comment: @Kari the "it" refers back to the title.

Comment: Ah sorry. I misread.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to substitute the value of $m$ into the expression $m+7$. So if $m=12$, $m+7$ is $19$. You can do this substitution for any expression

*Eg.* 
Let $x=4$, solve $x^2+1$
You'll just substitute in $4$ for $x$ and the expression becomes
$$4^2+1=17$$
Hope this also help clarify any future doubts.

Comment: $m+7$ is an expression not an equation.

Comment: @Karl Yeah, just realised that

Answer (score 0):

If $m=12$ then $m+7 = 12 + 7=19$.

Consider the function $y(m) = m + 7$. For every input $m$, you obtain a value $y(m)$ (dependent on values of $m$). So for $m=12$ you get $y(12) = 12 + 7=19$.